# Page does not load when pressing back on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a small project in asp.net core 3.

In one of the razor page I have this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="basic">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.activeSlides.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="~/source/Slides/@Model.activeSlides[i].Filename">@Model.activeSlides[i].Filename</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Move Up" asp-page-handler="MoveUp" asp-route-num="@i" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Move Down" asp-page-handler="MoveDown" asp-route-num="@i" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Archive" asp-page-handler="Archive" asp-route-num="@i" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
   ...
</form>
```

So each of the buttons has their own OnPost function.  Each of them modify an XML file and loads the same webpage.

```
public void OnPostMoveUp(string num)
{
    ...
}

public void OnPostMoveDown(string num)
{
    ...
}

public void OnPostArchive(string num)
{
    ...
}
```

I have noticed that when the buttons are used, they show the page handler and route in the URL.  E.g. `https://localhost:44342/screens/edit?num=2&handler=MoveUp`

The problem I am facing is after a button has been pressed, the user may select a hyperlink in the first column.  This is just an image, but the when the back button on the browser is pressed the page does not load.

P.S. I am not using MVC.

Comment: When the user selects the hyperlink are they moving to another page. When they click back do you want them to land on the previous page?

Comment: A back button does not trigger a page reload. It loads the page from cache.

Comment: The hyperlink takes them to an image.  When they click back I want the page to be visible, but the browser says the page is no longer available.  This only occurs when the back button returns to the URL with `?num=2&handler=MoveUp` in it.

Comment: Could you please tell me what happened when a user click the hyperlink? If possible, please upload a git image or else to let us to know what has happened.

Comment: The hyperlinks are just `https://localhost/source/slides/filename.png`.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by adding `Response.Redirect("/screens/edit");` at the end of all the OnPost methods.

This means the url params don't show therefore then clicking a link and choosing back on the browser now works.

This also fixes refreshing the page so it doesn't submit the form again.